# Typescript / Angular : equivalent of plus operator for boolean type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In typescript we can converter a string to a number using :

```
let asText: string = "123";
let asNumerals: number = +asText;
```

How can the same be achieved for boolean types :

```
let asText: string = "true";
console.log(+asText); // NaN
console.log(typeof asText); // string
let b: boolean = +asText; // does not compile
```

A pure JS approach yields correct results:

```
let b: boolean = asText == "true"; // Works as expected but not good enough
```

But this solution is not good enough, example :

```
<component input="true"></component>

@Component()
export class Component {

    @Input()
    private input: boolean;


    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(typeof input); // string
    }

}
```

Comment: `let b: boolean = asText == "true";` - why exactly it's not good enough?

Comment: As shown in my component, I first need to test if my boolean is boolean or string, and then convert it to boolean.

Comment: Your angular template code is buggy. If you want to pass an actual boolean as input, it should be `[input]="true"`. Otherwise, you're passing a string. Just fix the template code.

Comment: I don't think buggy is the word. It is the reason for the + opperator on numbers. Is there no equivelant for booleans ?

Comment: It is buggy. You shouldn't pass a string if the input is of type boolean. You can of course try to also accept the string "true", but where does it stop? Why no accept "TRUE", or "yes", or "on"? Just make things simple and clear: if the input is a boolean, then you accept booleans. If the caller messes up and passes a string, it's the caller's problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` operator performs type conversion for numbers. As for booleans, [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) terms are used to describe coerced value. Type conversion can be performed with `Boolean` built-in or `!!` shortcut; both `'false'` and `'true'` strings are truthy:

```
true === Boolean('true');
true === !!'false';
```

Since booleans can be either `true` or `false`, it doesn't make sense to parse string value. Considering that `'true'` would be converted to `true` and `'false'` would be converted to `false`, it's unclear what would `'foo'` string be converted to - there's no `NaN` counterpart for booleans, because they are booleans.

The particular problem is specific to Angular component input, as another answer mentions.

`input="true"` is equal to `input="{{ true }}"`, which is [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding), and input value will be a string.

While `[input]="true"` is [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-), and input value will be of the same type that was passed to the input. Boolean value will remain boolean and won't be needed to be converted.

Answer (score 3):

**`@input`** in the component should be represented with an **`[]`**, that should fix your issue

```
<component [input]="true"></component>
```